# Python: Writing a progress bar to a file

Tags: python

I have a python script that, as part of it, runs a perl script. I'm executing and capturing the `stdout` and `stderr` using the `subprocess` module; the pseudo code is:

```
import subprocess as sp
import sys
perl_script='/usr/.../foo.pl'
p = sp.Popen(perl_script,stdout=sp.PIPE,stderr=sp.PIPE)
fname='test.log'
shell_out=True
text = ''
with open(fname, 'w') as log:
    while True:
        data = p.stdout.read(1)
        if data == '' and p.poll() != None:
            break
        if data != '':
            if shell_out is True:
                sys.stdout.write(data)
                sys.stdout.flush()
            log.write(data)
    p.stdout.close()
```

For each iteration of the loop, data seems to be a single string character.

The issue I'm having is that this perl script displays a progress bar that it overwrites; something like:

```
[#####.....] 50%
```

and updates every 5%. As such, the log file I write to ends up having something along the lines of:

```
[#.........] 5% [##........] 10% [###.......] 15%
```

and so on.

Is there a method or way for me to write over the previous line in my log file, or is my only option to capture all of the text, try to modify it, then write it to a log file?

Edit: I think the simple nature of the example I gave might not tell the entire story. This perl script has multi progress bars (one for each task) and outputs additional information that I want to log. A more detailed example is:

```
NOTICE: one or more of things did stuff and you probably want to take note of it
writing the foo file . . .
    writing things . . .                             [####################] 100%
    writing stuff . . .                              [####################] 100%
    writing items . . .                              [####################] 100%
done
creating other files...
done
```

Keep in mind that the above output is an example that matches the characteristics of the stdout of this perl script, and that the real output (which I cannot post) is about 100 or so lines.

Finally, thanks for the formatting help :)

Edit #2: I've given up on trying to write the log file as `stdout` is being captured, and will instead store the `stdout` in a variable and write the log file after the script has finished. The only issue that remains is how to properly format the string so that the log file will be written correctly. The updated pseudo code is:

```
import subprocess as sp
import sys
tg_post='/usr/.../foo.pl'
p = sp.Popen(tg_post,stdout=sp.PIPE)
text = ''
fname='test.log'
shell_out=True
while True:
    data = p.stdout.read(1)
    if data == '' and p.poll() != None:
        break
    if data != '':
        if shell_out is True:
            sys.stdout.write(data)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        text += data        
p.stdout.close()
text = text.split('\r')
with open(fname, 'w') as log:
    log.write(text)
```

At the moment, this code results in a line for each percentage of each status bar. I suppose I could loop over each index in text (post-split) and remove an indices where there is a `#` and not a `100%`, but I'm hoping there is something more robust. If I `print text` (post-split), I get what I want on the screen. I know it's possible to use `print` to write to a file, but I'd like to avoid that (I believe that method isn't used anymore).

Comment: Why do you want to write over the lines in your log file?

Comment: @nathan.meadows - If I don't write over the lines in my log file, then instead of a ~100 line file that is easy to read, it's a ~50 line file where some lines are like 1600 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

You could define data outside of the while loop and write the last status to the file at the end. This way it will just write the last status update held by data to the file, which will avoid constantly overwriting the last status of the file.

```
import subprocess as sp
import sys
perl_script='/usr/.../foo.pl'
p = sp.Popen(perl_script,stdout=sp.PIPE,stderr=sp.PIPE)
fname='test.log'
shell_out=True
text = ''
data = ''

while True:
    data = p.stdout.read(1)
    if data == '' and p.poll() != None:
        break
    if data != '':
        if shell_out is True:
            sys.stdout.write(data)
            sys.stdout.flush()
    p.stdout.close()
with open(fname, 'w') as log:
    log.write(data)
```

Comment: The issue with that is that data is always a single character, so for the specifics of this perl script, this would result in a log file that is just `\n`. I could append `data` one each iteration, and then modify `data` after the loop, but I was hoping to be able to write the log file as I get the `stdout`.

Comment: Whats your reasoning of wanting to do it as you go? And [.strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) could be of use in that case

Comment: The more I think about it, the less important I think being about to write the log file as the `stdout` is capture. Given this, the only issue is how to format the text to remove all the lines that'd be overwritten. I'll update my original post accordingly.